# VB.NET call inside thread function

Tags: vb.net, multithreading

```
Public Class ThreadWithState
        ' State information used in the task. 
        Private locationx As Integer
        Private locationy As Integer

        ' The constructor obtains the state information. 
        Public Sub New(x As Integer, y As Integer)
            locationx = x
            locationy = y
        End Sub

        ' The thread procedure performs the task, such as formatting 
        ' and printing a document. 
        Dim win As New VBSoftKeyboard.KeyBoardForm
        Public Sub ThreadProc()
            'MessageBox.Show(locationy)
            Console.WriteLine(locationx, locationy)
            win.FormBorderStyle = Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None
            win.Location = New Point(locationx, locationy)
            win.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual
            Application.Run(win)
        End Sub

        Public Sub HideWin()
            win.Hide()
        End Sub


        Public Sub ShowWin()
           win.Show()
        End Sub
    End Class
Dim tws As New ThreadWithState(1000, 0) 'show the keyboard form location
    Private Sub SimpleButton1_Click_1(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles SimpleButton1.Click
        Dim t As New Thread(New ThreadStart(AddressOf tws.ThreadProc))
        t.Start()
        tws.HideWin() //PROBLEM HERE ! how to hide the form ? and when i want to use i can show the form
    End Sub
```

I use a thread to create a form, and then i m trying to hide the form first, when want to use the form i only call the `ShowWin()` function. `t` as thread to start the thread and create the form, how to call the `t` thread `HideWin()` function?

How to use created thread to call the others function ?

Comment: That is some bizarre code.  What are you actually trying to accomplish, i.e. why are you doing what you're doing?

Comment: @jmcilhinney i m doing virtual keyboard. do something like Android/iOS keyboard, when user clicked textbox. the virtual keyboard will show. but i need thread to create virtual keyboard. and use the thread to call show the form.

Comment: Exactly what benefit do you believe that using a secondary thread provides?

Comment: @jmcilhinney must use thread to create the form, otherwise the virtual keyboard will not functional. dont bother about it. my question is how to use created thread call another function. call `HideWin()` as well

Comment: It just seems odd to me that I've created an OSK before and not had to use a secondary thread but if that's the way you want to do it.

Comment: Anyway, you probably can't hide the window where you have that code because it probably hasn't even been shown yet.

Comment: @jmcilhinney `Application.Run(win)` <---- this code will show the form ! how come my runtime are show the form?

Comment: @jmcilhinney OSK? can write in Answer? any other method are welcome

Comment: `Application.Run` will display the form but who says that that `Application.Run` call will be made before the `HideWin` call?  Isn't the whole point of multiple threads to run in parallel?  `Thread.Start` isn't going to wait for `ThreadProc` to complete before returning so `HideWin` may well be called before `Application.Run`.

Comment: @jmcilhinney tried before called Applicaiton.run, same result. the form wont hide.